# Orchard CMS: Setting Content Type Urls to include type

Tags: url, orchardcms

I finally took a look at Orchard and I find it very impressive. One thing has me confused, however.

It appears that all content items and pages created are set as relative to the root. The only exception to this appears to be the blog, where a post is set to be a subpage of the blog that contains it.

How do I get my custom content type to mimic this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this is done under the covers but the container and containable parts result in the same effect.

Create customType A and add the container part.
Create customType B and add the containable part.

Create a content item of type A (itemA). 
Create a content item of type B and add it to itemA.

You should then be able to navigate to /itemA/itemB if you set the slugs accordingly.

There is a slight nuance in the content create screen where the slug's path will be missing 'itemA' but it will show up when you refresh.

Comment: thank you this is very helpful, but I don't want to use a custom container type, I want to use list. I created a venue, and added to a list of Venues, however the url is still set to the root. I can navigate to /venues and see a list of venues, but when I click the items the url is at the root

Comment: okay I reloaded the page and indeed the slug IS there from the name of the list. I republished the venue item and it sure works! thanks!